# Carousel Vue Awesome Swiper has bug looping

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, swiper.js

I'm working in Nuxt and i Have a bug with a carousel from Vue Awesome Swiper, my problem is it doesn't looping infinity like i hope, this have multiple slider, i think it's the problem
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dVbYL.png) 
When I want to go to the products on the left it does not end at the end of the cycle, and so on the contrary, if I go to the end the following elements do not send me to the beginning of the cycle

This my code for set up

```
swiperOption3: {
        initialSlide: 0,
        freeMode: true,
        slidesPerView: 2,
        slidesPerGroup: 1,
        loop: true,
        loopFillGroupWithBlank: true,
        autoplay: {
          delay: 2000,
          disableOnInteraction: false
        },

        breakpoints: {
          1024: {
            slidesPerView: 2,
            spaceBetween: 10
          },
          868: {
            slidesPerView: 2,
            spaceBetween: 20
          },
          800: {
            slidesPerView: 2,
            spaceBetween: 10
          },
          768: {
            slidesPerView: 1,
            spaceBetween: 0
          },
          640: {
            slidesPerView: 2,
            spaceBetween: 10
          },
          500: {
            slidesPerView: 1,
            spaceBetween: 10
          },
          320: {
            slidesPerView: 1,
            spaceBetween: 10
          }
        }
      }
```

and this is a summary of my html

```
<swiper
    :options="swiperOption3"
    style="min-height:290px; margin-top:2%"
    ref="swiperMaxCard"
  >
    <swiper-slide
      v-for="(item, index) in imagenes"
      :key="index"
      style="text-align: -webkit-center;"
    >  

   <div v-if="
          index != $refs.swiperMaxCard.swiper.activeIndex + 1 &&
            !$vuetify.breakpoint.smOnly
        "></div>
<div  v-if="index == $refs.swiperMaxCard.swiper.activeIndex + 1 ||
            $vuetify.breakpoint.smOnly
        "></div>


</swiper-slide>
  </swiper>
```

In code it looks like this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RByWx.png), but if it's working should have many copys of the DOM, it works with one slider for view. I saw that several people have worked, but still report cases of a bug in the loop, this is the tool https://github.com/surmon-china/vue-awesome-swiper